# How to Install SQL Server 2017 on RPI4 Ubuntu 18.04 64bit version

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install SQL Server 2017 on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to install following the installation below https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15, but I am getting error like **unable to locate package**.

Please anyone help on this, resolve the problem.

Comment: What is "*SQL Server 2017*"? What command do you use to install it? Please [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/109156/edit) your question and add the information to it.

Comment: You can't run SQL Server for an X86_64 microprocessor on your ARM microprocessor. It's built for the wrong architecture. Also I doubt whether Microsoft would want to sell you a software licence to run MSSQL on anything other than their Windows OS.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Why are you trying to do that? Is there any mature purpose? However, there is a lot of DB waiting for you to install them. ;-)